# How can I make VS Code show full TypeScript type definitions on mouse hover?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm converting a React project from using JSX to using TSX files.

I need full preview of types of one constant:

```
const canvasProps = {
  setPorts,
  setBoxes,
  setLines,
  selected,
  setSelected,
  actionState,
  setActionState,
  ... // and more
};
```

on hover on `canvasProps` I get the preview:

```
const canvasProps: {
    setPorts: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{
        shape: string;
        id: string;
        name: string;
        port: portType;
        ref: any;
    }[]>>;
    setBoxes: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<BoxType[]>>;
    ... 13 more ...;
    toggleFlowVisibility: (flow: any) => void;
}
```

I need to get the full type definition of this constant, which means see the extra 13 types.

(I need this because I need to declare the properties of `React.Context`, which depends on functions that have not declared yet (inside a function component) )

So how can I get the full type definition without working hard?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Where `canvasProps` comes from? Is it an object you declared, or is it declared by 3rd party?

Comment: it's object declared inside my 'main' react component, and then this object is used as my context value object (that all the child components using).
the thing is, I need to define a context using `React.createContext` outside the main component so all the other children will be able to import it, so I need to predefine the types of each var in this object.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what about make the context structure as interface? so, first, you'll be typesafe when you change the context and second, consume that type in the children.

Comment: Here is a tiny project for a reference - https://github.com/godon019/typescript-react-useContext-example/tree/master/

Comment: thank you for the example, but this exactly what I'm trying to do. 
but want to take the interface types from VS code inferring  (from `canvasProps`). 
(because canvasProps already exists it will make me easier just to copy types inferring from it to the context interface, I've already done it by hand, but it would be much easier if there was **option to show all full type preview**)

Comment: Agreed. I tried to dig into vscode codebase to find where exactly this tooltip content been calculated but seems it's out vscode itself (but probably it's just me). This is how far I went: https://github.com/moshfeu/vscode/blob/73dfd92e65e213aba107fa0d3b722d17183a1706/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/features/hover.ts#L40. Anyway, it smells like a feature request, or a question on Github, at least.

Comment: yup, if it's doesn't exist, you right.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Setting `"noErrorTruncation": true`, as proposed in the previous answer, does *not* work for this question as asked.

A quick fix that actually does work would be… a more offensive solution ;p

Start by opening

```
<Microsoft VS Code install folder>/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js
```

And, around line 13471 (so far), change:

```
ts.defaultMaximumTruncationLength = 160
```

to something higher, like

```
ts.defaultMaximumTruncationLength = 800
```

This will get you what you are waiting for. A nice 800 chars long max type definition on hover. You can, of course, custom this as much as you want.

This might not be maintainable as you will need to do it again after every Visual Studio Code update, but it works just fine, and you'll finally get your full type on hover.

Note that you'll need to restart your tsServer. To do so in Visual Studio Code:

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Type `restart ts server`
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

wait a couple seconds, it's fairly quick.

Comment: Hey, I believe that this is how it would on a windows machine or maybe linux machine, is that right? I'm trying to achieve the same thing on macOS, but I can't seem to find this defaultMaximumTruncationLength option. Do you have any idea where I should be able to find this option on macOS?

Comment: Hi there,

Well I'm sorry to report that this has been done on a mac at the time of posting. I couldn't say if they changed it or not :/

Comment: Oh really? Then I got confused because the keyboard shortcuts that you named contained a ctrl and not a command, if you know what I mean.

Comment: You are totally right!
However, this post has been written on a windows computer ;-p, that's probably the reason I used ctrl instead of cmd!

Comment: On a Mac, browse to "Visual Studio Code" in Applications, Ctrl-click it, select "Show Package Contents", navigate to the above file, and open in an editor.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across the same problem and found a very useful extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kimuson.ts-type-expand. This calculates and shows the full type definition on the explorer sidebar.

I am in no way associated with this extension.

Comment: This is really cool. It would be awesome if there was an option to have this functionality inside the tooltip though.

Answer (score 2):

Hm. The top <sup><sub>(at the time of this writing)</sub></sup> answer claims that [`"noErrorTruncation": true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noErrorTruncation) (put in the `compilerOptions` of your tsconfig.json) doesn't work, but at least for a simple example I tried, it really does make a difference:

```js
const canvasProps = {
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1: 1,
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2: 2,
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3: 3,
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4: 4,
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa5: 5,
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa6: 6,
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa7: 7,
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8: 8,
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa9: 9,
}
```

With `"noErrorTruncation": true`, the VS Code hover info shows the full type, but without it, it only shows

```js
const canvasProps: {
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1: number;
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2: number;
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3: number;
    ... 5 more ...;
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa9: number;
}
```

In any case, you'll probably be interested in the following issue tickets:

- [Interactive Diagnostics
  #64566](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64566)
- [Option to expand computed TypeScript types on hover #94679](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94679)
- [Add full type hover popup to VS Code commands #35601](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35601)

You can give them a thumbs up to show support for them and subscribe to them to get notified about discussions and progress. <sup><sub>[But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

Another workaround someone suggested at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35601#issuecomment-921752554 is to edit tsserver itself to increase the threshold before it starts truncating. There's a line in tsserver.js that does `ts.defaultMaximumTruncationLength =` that sets the threshold. You can edit that file. For the TypeScript that comes with VS Code (if you don't use the `typescript.tsdk` VS Code setting), that's somewhere like in `/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js` of the VS Code installation. If you use `typescript.tsdk`, then you'd edit the typescript installed in your workspace folder's `node_modules`. This is probably flaky though. VS Code might issue a corruption warning if you edit its files, and if you reinstall / update your `node_modules` typescript, then you'll need to make that modification again.

For your reference and learning purposes, the above issue tickets were found by googling "`github vscode issues typescript hover info type more`".