# Consistent Typescript Array representation in Visual Studio popups

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to be consistent about the way it represents `Array<>` types in TypeScript? I'd prefer it to encapsulate the type in `Array` (like it is written) all the time instead tacking `[]` to the end because the former is much more readable on long types (much easier to follow what is part of the array and also reads left to right much better)

[image]

```
const myType: Array<{ prop1: Array<string>, prop2: string }> = {};
```

Comment: You've tagged this with [visual-studio] and not [visual-studio-code], so I'll let others chime in with an answer. If you are in fact using VSCode, you may want to try the solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62508909/215552) a try. It talks about `noErrorTruncation`, but it seems to affect more than errors.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The tag is, in fact, correct. I am not using VS Code.

Comment: Could you make a screenshot with both [] and Array ised as props in a type?

Comment: @Dimava the screen shot in the question demonstrates how I declared it (with `Array`), and the various ways the popup references it (with `Array` and `[]` inconsistently)

Comment: I'm sure it's just a typo in your post, but when you instantiated myType, you assigned it to an empty object not an empty array, which would indeed cause the error your seeing. Do you get the same error when you assign myType to an empty object?

Comment: That's intentional to show an error message. Even if I `= []` then the type represented by the popup in VS shows [the same](https://imgur.com/a/cgEDc4o) (IMO) poorly formatted type.

Answer (score 0):

Type errors are provided by Typescript Language Server as **text**, so making them look different by changing Typescript configuration is impossible
(the messages look the same in every editor there is)

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/server/protocol.ts#L2811

[image]

If you want to change how they look like, you'll need an equivalent of https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yoavbls.pretty-ts-errors or https://www.totaltypescript.com/vscode-extension extension that modifies how the error is *displayed*

[image]

Comment: Those extensions look interesting though they are for VSCode, unfortunately. I will note that my issue isn't just with errors but but with every representation of an array type. So even types which are perfectly valid and I've typed as `Array<string>` will get converted to `string[]` in the hover text.

Comment: @Brad hmm, so your problem is also that when `Array<T>` gets instantiated it becomes written as `T[]`

Comment: That's correct. My complaint related to that is that visually parsing types is harder because of it. My eyes are going left to right and as I read the type and I get to `[]` I then need to go back and figure out where the array thing started. And depending on how the type is used the hover text might stay `Array` or it might get flipped to `[]`. Consider these two types `type WhereCriteria = (input: Array<KeyModel<string, boolean>>) => void` and another type like `type Criteria = Array<KeyModel<string, boolean>>;`, if I mouse over the former it will say `KeyModel<string, boolean>[]`...

Comment: ... and if I mouse over the latter it will be unchanged from what was written in the .ts file. I'd like to avoid that visual left-right-left-right when reading types and for the types to be represented how they're actually written.

Answer (score -1):

There ist actually a difference between `Array` and `[]`. Take a Look at this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931875/18998794). Here ist also an additional [TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36843084/18998794) explanation, which points out your problem between the Type difference.

Comment: I concur that there is not a difference (except maybe where there is with readonly? in which case `[]` is ambiguous). I'd like the type to be rendered in the hovertext the same way it is written. Putting the `[]` at the end makes visually parsing the type onerous.