# Is there a way to access typings of a prop in VS Code without having to check the types files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a property with a type that is a union type of 70ish string members (it comes from chakra ui).

[image: screenshot]

I need to know every type used in the union type, i.e I want the full list of types. The problem here is that VS Code has inferred them but will only display a number of them and just display "62 more", and trying to find all of the types used in this union type is extremely hard, because of how their types are structured.

Is there a way to print all of these types at once? Get a full list of them? VS Code can infer them from the property so is it possible to log those types somehow?

Comment: "_I need to know every type used in the union type, i.e I want the full list of types_": You can use a technique like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND844N), where you just copy + paste a few times to build your own list... but more importantly: **What do you plan to do with the expanded list of types?**

Comment: @jsejcksn I need to know all the types because I want to bridge this width property with another component that also has a width property but expects 'normal' css values (px, %...) and not custom chakra values ('sm', '1', ...) so I'm going to map those values to pixels.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138599/is-there-a-way-to-access-typings-of-a-prop-in-vs-code-without-having-to-check-th#comment134279818_76138599) How will you determine which values are handled as a special case by chakra?

Comment: @jsejcksn values won't be handled by chakra in this use case, basically I have a component that accept "chakra values", like "sm", "1", etc... I also have a hook that provides me those chakra sizes and their values in rem. I can just map those sizes to their equivalent in rem, so you can pass width="sm" to the component but it will pass width="...rem" to the image that it renders. I needed to know the full list of types because I needed to make sure of what values are expected by this component.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138599/is-there-a-way-to-access-typings-of-a-prop-in-vs-code-without-having-to-check-th?noredirect=1#comment134299619_76138599) Understood — I'm just pointing out that the types for any given code don't necessarily align with runtime values/logic — and that you should look to the [source](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui) runtime code to make your determination instead of the type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting [`"noErrorTruncation": true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noErrorTruncation) in the `compilerOptions` section of your tsconfig.json.

If that doesn't work, in your particular case with the members all being literal values (string literals), you can just create a context where the value to fill it is of that type, and then trigger suggestions (use the `Trigger Suggest` command in the command palette, or whatever keyboard shortcut it's bound to. Ex. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> on Windows and Linux). Here's a small example:

```js
type a = "0"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6";
const a: a = /* <- put cursor here and trigger suggestions. you'll see the union members listed */;
```

There's a more general case of this question asked here: [VS code how to show full typescript definition on mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62508909/11107541). I've chosen not to vote to close this as a duplicate since in your particular case there is the workaround I've described above.

In the more general case, you'll probably be interested in the following issue tickets:

- [Interactive Diagnostics
  #64566](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64566)
- [Option to expand computed TypeScript types on hover #94679](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94679)
- [Add full type hover popup to VS Code commands #35601](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35601)

You can give them a thumbs up to show support for them and subscribe to them to get notified about discussions and progress. <sup><sub>[But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>